# can we upload a file from put or post in netlib?

Tags: c++, boost, cpp-netlib

I want some server for my post or put request in cpp.I have choose netlib.. so i want to know that can we upload some xml or json file from put or post request in netlib.

Can anyone answer this question. because i m struck with this.

Thanks
Vishnkumar.

Comment: Have you checked the [examples](http://cpp-netlib.org/latest/examples.html) page for cpp-netlib?